# Trimming keys in a closure

Tags: php, arrays, closures, php-5.4

I'm having an issue with my closure returning the keys that it has operated on as an array, what am I doing wrong?

Input:

```
$array = array(
    '/key1/'        => null,
    '/key2/part1/'  => null,
);
```

Method:

```
    /**
     * Trim slashes from keys or strings
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return array|string
     */
    private function trimSlashes($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            array_walk($value, function($val, $key) USE (&$value)
            {
                if (FALSE !== strpos($key, '/')) $key = rtrim($key, '/');
            });
        } else {
            $value = rtrim($value, '/');
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

This should return:

```
$array = array(
    '/key1'         => null,
    '/key2/part1'   => null,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible that array_walk can be used to change keys in the array.
Maybe you can get $value as a classmember instead of reference in your closure.
But i think its better to iterate it with a foreach-loop, like this..

```
private function trimSlashes($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                unset($value[$key]);
                $trimmedKey = rtrim($key, '/');
                $value[$trimmedKey] = $val;
             }
        } else {
            $value = rtrim($value, '/');
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: this will unset all keys.

Comment: that is right, but it will set new keys (trimmed keys). that is the goal. Oh i saw what you mean. I fixed the code.